# Database backup taking longer than usual to a networkshare

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup

The SQL server does backups with this command to a network share \BackupServer\weekeklybackups"

```
BACKUP DATABASE DBNAME TO DISK = '\\BackupServer\weekeklybackups\DBNAME.BAK'
```

There is a 1 gig network between the SQL Databse server and the BackupServer. but it uses maximum 25% of the network, so the backup is taking for ever.
If I make the database locally and copy it over to the same network share, it is faster using 99% of the network bandwidh.

So, the weekly automated backups are taking a long time, which is an issues

When I check the monitor it says it is waiting with "ASYNC_IO_...". When I did some google search it says, this is an issue on tape backup. But this is on iSCSI hard

disks. and manual copy over works fine. So, what could be the issue? It was working fine for a year until last week. Not sure what happened. but where should I be

looking in to?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Backup operation reads data from disk and writes to disk/tape. Now in your case I guess slowness is from SQL server side. May be the disk on which SQL server data files reside is facing |I/O contention which is causing whole process to slow down. Async IO completion is pointer to slow disk or I/O contention. Its quite possible because of  SQL server under I/O pressure. Can you confirm load on server ?

Comment: It would not affect data file as such but backup has to read data from disk where data files reside if disk is slow or facing I/O contention backup would not get I/O *eaisly* and would have to wait thus causing delay

Comment: Thanks Shanky. but wouldn't that cause the slowness when I have the .bak file on the local hard drive where the data files are to the network share. It is faster in that. using 99% of the network link. But I will check the load on the server.

Comment: Shanky - http://screencast.com/t/irmCL3a01w. Here is the Activity monitor output. It is active but nothing alarming here. Should I check any other parameters for the load?

Comment: Can you post output for below counters for Object Physical disk: Avg. Disk sec/Transfer
Avg. Disk Queue Length
Avg. Disk sec/Read
Disk reads/sec  please measure this for more than 15 mins and post the value here. Please measure this counter for disk on which data file is residing

Comment: Thanks Shanky. Here is the PerfMon results on the Data Drive http://screencast.com/t/4MtOzFkxvb

Comment: Well I was expecting a numerical value instead of pictorial.Can you do that please from fig disk reads/sec is high for small duration but I dont sense disk issue here can you try taking backup during offpeak hour and see if you still feel slowness. Did you had look at network utilization

Comment: I try now being almost 5 pm here. it is the. The network utility is 25% where it used to be 99%.

Comment: there is one more thing. I tried the same thing from another very similar database server. It is doing the same thing. I am wondering if it is to do with the Disks on the network backup server.

Comment: Also, if I do a restore from the same network storage it uses 99% of the network line; it is only the backup that is being effected. Can the disks lose writing speed overnight??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15749/discussion-between-shanky-and-user3618129).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was a hardware issue that has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issues on the hard drive. It never showed any errors in event viewer or the controller. When we rebooted the server, the errors showed up and we replaced the drives.